# Django - URL regex pattern

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a model named Tag and I have many of these in my database.
I want to access them in a page via a URL on the following way:

If I want to see Tags with id 1, 3 and 4, then the URL should end up in 134.
What regex pattern should I use in order to get, lets say, a list [1,3,4] from a URL like /.../134/?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need fixed width tag identifiers (e.g. 001003004), otherwise it's ambiguous. If you use that, you can just capture `\d+` and then do something like this in the view:

```
>>> import re
>>> tag_string = "001003004"
>>> regex = re.compile("\d{3}")
>>> tag_list = map(int, regex.findall(tag_string))
[1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be difficult/impossible to do with just a regex if both A.) the number of consecutive digits in the URL is arbitrary, and B.) you need to return each number to your code individually.

If you only need to grab the string of digits (then parse it later in your code), you could just use this:
`/(\d+)/` (escape the /'s if they're used as delimiters)

Then you could just run some string manipulation on $1

If you need the regex to return each digit as $1, $2, $3, etc, I believe the only solution would be something rather inelegant, like this:

```
/(\d)(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?/
```

...in which case it would support a maximum of 10 tags in the URL.